# I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and install windows 8

Tags: installation, windows-8, uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and install windows 8 via USB. I have a bootable usb stick and boot order is set to boot from the USB stick but it takes me directly to the GNU GRUB screen instead with no option of selecting the USB. Any idea on what needs to happen?

Comment: which software did you use to make bootable windows usb?

Comment: I used UNetbootin, found in the software center

Comment: did you try pressing F8 Or F9 After Creating Your Bootable and rebooting your computer?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu/381560#381560

Comment: if you use unetbootin to create bootable windows usb in ubuntu,it won't work.See the link i posted.

Answer (score 0):

One of many reasons maybe that your computer has UEFI which makes him unbootable from NTFS pendrive.
Check if directory /sys/firmware/efi on your Ubuntu exists - if so, youre system was booted in U/EFI.